# Change point location

Tags: vba, catia

I want, when a point is selected, the co ordinate values of the point to display in a userform:
[image]

Values of x, y & z should be displayed in the textboxes.

Some points are in "ONCURVE" or "ONSURFACE" type. Those points won't show x, y & z values.
Image for reference
[image]

First point is **co-ordinate** defined, second point is **ONCurve** defined and the third is **ONSURFACE** defined.

How do I extract x y z co-ordinate values for those points?

I also need to change the point location by changing the values from the textbox.

Comment: They are all different point types, but have the same base point type so editing may be different for each. Start with "Insert Object Resolution" in the VBA editor and select a point from the tree. Explore the properties of the point objects. You should be able to extract the absolute coordinates from each type. Come back with a little more code and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

As GisMofx said, you should use the base Point class and you can use the methods GetCoordinates

Take a look in the API documentation - you should be able to find some examples and if not try to come up with something

[CATIA API Point Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jLeH.png)